# Force a UIView to redraw immediately, instead of during next run loop

Tags: iphone, uiview

I've created a UIImagePicker / camera view, with a toolbar and custom button for taking a snapshot. I can't really change to using the default way because of the custom button, and I'm drawing on top of the view.

When you hit the button, I want to take a screenshot using UIGetScreenImage(); however, the toolbar is showing up in the image, even if I hide it first:

```
//hide the toolbar
self.toolbar.hidden = YES; 

// capture the screen pixels
CGImageRef screenCap = UIGetScreenImage();
```

I'm pretty sure this is because even though the toolbar is hidden, it gets redrawn once the function returns and we enter the next run loop - after UIGetScreenImage is called.

I tried making the following addition, but it didn't help:

```
//hide the toolbar
self.toolbar.hidden = YES; 
[self.toolbar drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 52)];

// capture the screen pixels
CGImageRef screenCap = UIGetScreenImage();
```

I also tried using setNeedsDisplay, but that doesn't work either because once again the draw happens after the current function returns.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try hiding the UI elements in a separate selector, and using the `-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` method, using `YES` for the `waitUntilDone` argument. Then follow that up with another selector for screen capture.

Comment: This alone didn't do it, but a minor addition got it working. I called the screen capture selector with [self performSelector:@selector(captureScreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:0]; and that got the job done. Thanks for the lead!

Comment: [self performSelector:@selector(captureScreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:0]; actually makes "captureScreen" run on the next run loop.

Answer (score 8):

The update is done in the run loop.

Simply add :

> self.toolbar.hidden = YES;
>
> [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
>   runUntilDate: [NSDate
>   dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 0.01]];
>
> CGImageRef screenCap =
>   UIGetScreenImage();

Comment: This does the job and is simpler to implement, thanks Antoine.