# What is the correct way to update a Wait View and UI during an NSURLRequest in iOS 8/9?

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsurlrequest

I  want know the best pattern to update a Wait View and UI during an NSURLRequest in iOS 8/9.

In my model the NSURLRequest is handle in a singleton and comunicate with the caller class by delegate.

Personaly I show the a Wait View in the main thread, the I call dataTaskWithRequest:request in my singleton and finally I update the delegate (A viewController) in the completitionHandler. The problem is that some time the Wait View is showed after some seconds and some client (iOS9 only) report random crash calling dataTaskWithRequest.

```
 [APP_DELEGATE  startWaitWithText:@"Please Wait"];

     NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                    NSURLResponse *response,
                                    NSError *error) {

                    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                         [APP_DELEGATE stopWait];
                         [delegate updateUI:data,response,error];
                    });

              }] resume];
```

Edit. My Wait View

```
#define TAG_WINDOW_WAIT 10001
- (void) startWaitWithText:(NSString*) text
{
    [self stopWaitModal];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        backgrView =[[self window] viewWithTag:TAG_WINDOW_WAIT];
        if(!backgrView)
        {
            backgrView= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
            [[self window] addSubview:backgrView];
        }

        backgrView.tag = TAG_WINDOW_WAIT;
        [backgrView becomeFirstResponder];
        [[self window] bringSubviewToFront:backgrView];

    });
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your code is called from the main thread (specifically the `startWaitWithText:`)? In case whatever you're doing after calling `startWaithWithText:` takes a long time, you may force the wait view to show as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4596185/727817 . As for the crash, you'll need to give more info (crash log/message).

Comment: I'have added StartWait View. But the question is about the correct pattern to use in iOS9

Comment: The logic looks fine, calling start and stop for the wait view on the main thread. The crash is probably not related to your wait view, but with something else (considering it's failing on `dataTaskWithRequest`). The wait view should show without delay, as long as the main thread is not busy with something else.